# Toggle Windows Menu Item Checkbox in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, menuitem

I'm trying to toggle the checkbox next to my menu item and also change a bool in my code to correspond with whether the menu item is checked or not.

I have a `case` in my `switch (message) { ... }` inside my `WndProc` function for the specific menu item. I also have a bool variable set to `TRUE` and my menu item is checked by default.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```
HMENU hmenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
LPMENUITEMINFO menuItem;
GetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, ID_OPTIONS_COMPUTERDELAY, FALSE, &menuItem);

if (menuItem->fState == MFS_CHECKED) {
    // Checked, uncheck it
    menuItem->fState = MFS_UNCHECKED;
    SetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, ID_OPTIONS_COMPUTERDELAY, FALSE, &menuItem);
} else {
    // Unchecked, check it
    menuItem->fState = MFS_CHECKED;
    SetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, ID_OPTIONS_COMPUTERDELAY, FALSE, &menuItem);
}
```

**I receive the following errors (line numbers were changed to match code above):**

```
Line 3: argument of type "LPMENUITEMINFO *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPMENUITEMINFOW"
Line 8: argument of type "LPMENUITEMINFO *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCMENUITEMINFOW"
Line 12: argument of type "LPMENUITEMINFO *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCMENUITEMINFOW"
Line 4: 'BOOL GetMenuItemInfoW(HMENU,UINT,BOOL,LPMENUITEMINFOW)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'LPMENUITEMINFO *' to 'LPMENUITEMINFOW'
```

Comment: The  `menuItem` should be `MENUITEMINFO` **not** `LPMENUITEMINFO`

Comment: Also, per the [`GetMenuItemInfo()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx): "*Note that you must set the `cbSize` member to `sizeof(MENUITEMINFO)` before calling this function*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetMenuItemInfo()` and `SetMenuItemInfo()` expect a pointer to an allocated `MENUITEMINFO` instance, but you are passing them a pointer to an uninitialized `MENUITEMINFO*` pointer instead.  That is why you are getting errors.

You also have to set the `cbSize` and `fMask` fields before calling `GetMenuItemInfo()`.

Try this instead:

```
HMENU hmenu = GetMenu(hWnd);

MENUITEMINFO menuItem = {0};
menuItem.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
menuItem.fMask = MIIM_STATE;

GetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, ID_OPTIONS_COMPUTERDELAY, FALSE, &menuItem);

if (menuItem.fState == MFS_CHECKED) {
    // Checked, uncheck it
    menuItem.fState = MFS_UNCHECKED;
} else {
    // Unchecked, check it
    menuItem.fState = MFS_CHECKED;
}
SetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, ID_OPTIONS_COMPUTERDELAY, FALSE, &menuItem);
```